# Is it safe to initialize RecyclerView item in onNext of Observable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java

I use `RecyclerView` to show a list of items which have dates on them and to format the date on non UI thread I want to use RxJava. 
So this is the code of my `Observable`

```
public Observable<String> getDateFormatObservable(){
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                if(date == null){
                    if(!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()){
                        subscriber.onNext(dateStr);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                    return;
                }

                String formatedDate = "";

                if(DateUtils.isToday(date)){
                    formatedDate = DateFormat.format("H:m", date).toString();
                } else {
                    formatedDate = DateFormat.format("d MMM yyyy", date).toString();
                }

                if(!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()){
                    subscriber.onNext(formatedDate);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is the code of my subscriber:

```
public void initDate(final TextView dateTv){
    getDateFormatObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) {
                    dateTv.setText(s);
                }
            });
}
```

I call this `initDate` method from the `onBindViewHolder` and pass the corresponding `TextView` to it.

So the question is - is it safe to do so? Can there be some problems because of recycling? For example if I scroll fast, can there be a case when wrong date is set to a TextView?

P.S. When I test now, it seems that everything is OK, but I think that there can be a case when the `OnNext` of a date is called when its corresponding TextView is already out of screen and recycled and this date may be set to a wrong TextView. But surprisingly it seems not to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preparing data during scroll is quite bad idea in general (`CursorAdapter` is another story). I suppose in your case everything works ok because of your code

```
if(DateUtils.isToday(date)){
    formatedDate = DateFormat.format("H:m", date).toString();
} else {
    formatedDate = DateFormat.format("d MMM yyyy", date).toString();
}
```

It just executes quite fast. Don't know what happens in `DateUtils.isToday` but I think you could run it in `UI Thread` and everything will work ok and your code will be much simpler.

The other problem that without caching you constantly construct `formatedDate` which is just senseless.

Most common method is to load data by pages and pass it into adapter. You could create `Pojo/Model` object and store your data in it:

```
public class Model{
    String formatedDate;
    //other fields
}
```

Instead of calling `getDateFormatObservable` you could create methods which returns list of models which already contain all necessary data for visible amount of list(RecyclerView) items:

```
Observable<List<Model>> getModels(long fromDate, long toDate);
```

When user reaches the end of list you need to call the method to load next page of data.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It helped me to find a better solution. I changed the logic completely and now I format the date as soon as I get these objects from REST API and store the formatted date in objects before I begin to show them in the list.